# Checking PostGIS point geometry?

Tags: postgis, pointgeometry

I originated some points with incorrect geometries (ex: 1432.33 , 900.2 for EPSG4326) because lat/lon in data source where also incorrect.

How can I detect in the_geom these incorrect ones?

I think `ST_IsValid` is not useful, as the `ST_Geometry` is well formed, even if its data inside is not.

Answer (score 2):

Prevent these by either [using a `geography` type](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#PostGIS_Geography), which forbid these coordinates, or add a check constraint for the geometry column (e.g., `geom` on `my_table`):

```sql
ALTER TABLE my_table
  ADD CONSTRAINT valid_long_lat CHECK (
    ST_XMin(geom) >= -180 AND ST_XMax(geom) <= 180 AND
    ST_YMin(geom) >= -90 AND ST_YMax(geom) <= 90);
```

Comment: or you can create polygon for "correct" area and use it as constraint. If your data is only one one country you can http://www.gadm.org/ shapefiles

Answer (score 1):

You could query the Point Geometry's X & Y coordinates by using the [`ST_X`](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_X.html) & [`ST_Y`](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Y.html).

Your query could be something like:

```sql
SELECT * from table 
    where (ST_X(the_geom)>180) OR (ST_X(the_geom)<-180) OR (ST_Y(the_geom)>90)
    OR (ST_Y(the_geom)<-90)
```

Comment: slightly more compact: `ST_X(the_geom) not between -180 and 180 or ST_Y(the_geom) not between -90 and 90`

Answer (score 0):

Consider [postgis_latlon](https://github.com/adamatan/postgis_latlon), an open-source utility suite for PostGIS that I've written to solve similar problems.

```
latlon_is_valid(geom)
```

Returns `false` if any of the points in the geometry has a lat not in `[-90, 90]` or lon not in `[-180, 180]`.

The package is still in Beta, looking forward for any comments.